# How can I pull and return variables from a list?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm working on a project and want to create a function that will take a logical proposition in the form of a list as input and return a new list consisting of the variable names.

For example:
`(A and (not B or C))` would return `(A B C)`

But I'm having a hard time with looping through the input list, especially when it involves nested lists like in the example.

edit: Thanks, got some code that works:

```
(define (flatten list)
  (cond ((null? list) '())
    ((pair? (car list))
     (append (flatten (car list))
             (flatten (cdr list))))
    (else (cons (car list) (flatten (cdr list))))))

(define (remove-element list)
  (filter (lambda (x) 
        (and (and (and (not (equal? x 'and)) 
             (not (equal? x 'or)))
             (and (not (equal? x 'implies))
             (not (equal? x 'not)))     )
             (not (equal? x 'iff))))
      (flatten list)))
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure _what_ it is you're asking.  Do you want to filter out certain elements in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical beginner assignment is to flatten a list. You'll find lots of questions here about that and basically it will make `'(A and (not B or C))` into `(A and not B or C)`. Then you're almost there.

Basically there is no distinction between a variable and an operator since eg. `not` can come before  and `and` can come between. I guess you cannot have variable names that are the same as your operators and you need to know the operators in advance. Then you can filter the flattened list to remove the operators. you'll then be left with `(A B C)`.

It's difficult helping with specifics when you don't even have any code in your question so this is a s far as I can help you. Good luck.